# Use of code generation in flutter for production code among a team?

Tags: flutter, code-generation, project-management, build-runner

Is it possible to specify a single file to `flutter package pub run build runner`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the build_runner build --help output:

```
--build-filter                  An explicit filter of files to build.
                                    Relative paths and `package:` uris are
                                    supported, including glob syntax for paths
                                    portions (but not package names).
```

There is an example in their changelog:

> Example: The following would build and serve the JS output for an
> application, as well as copy over the required SDK resources for that
> app:

```
pub run build_runner serve \
  --build-filter="web/main.dart.js" \
  --build-filter="package:build_web_compilers/**/*.js"
```

https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner/changelog#170